# How to copy a collection along with all its subcollections and save that as a new collection in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I accidentally made a mistake in a firestore collection name and would like to rename it but there is no option to rename a collection in firestore. There is an option to export and then import the collection to GCP using the following command:

> gcloud firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME] --collection-ids=[COLLECTION_ID_1],[COLLECTION_ID_2]

Will this only reexport the collection with the same name. Is there any other way to do this other than writing a script or doing it manually?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the names and IDs of collections and documents (or in other words, change the path of the document), the only way to do that is to read each document, then write it to its new location.  This typically involves writing code to perform a query, iterate the results, write new documents, and delete the originals.

Unless you are able to find a library to do all this for you, you'll have to write the code yourself.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of writing a script to do it. But it's a small collection so I might as well do it manually. Anyways, thanks for the reply.